# Trying to define function inside html of popModal jQuery library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to copy the functionality of [JSFiddle#1](https://jsfiddle.net/otsnaL49/1/) into my [JSFiddle#2](https://jsfiddle.net/walker123/b3u0pq4c/)

**Brief Description of above two fiddles:**

**1) JSfiddle #1 :** When a user selects `third` option from the dropdown menu, it displays the alert popup.

**2) JSFiddle #2:** I have tried to plug in the `JSFiddle #1` code into this fiddle inside the  `html: $('#name_status_popup_dialog').html(),` as shown in the fiddle (commented lines of code) but it doesn't work. The reason I am putting it inside `html: $('#name_status_popup_dialog').html(),` is because it is responsible for displaying the HTML contents in the dialog. [Here is the documentation](https://github.com/vadimsva/popModal) of `html` parameter used in the `popModal` library. Am I defining the function for the popup dialog correctly inside `html()` for JsFiddle #2? Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as putting the code outside of `html` callback. See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b3u0pq4c/6/).

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var id_value;
  $(document).on('change', '#change_name_statusName', function checkSelection() {
    const change_name_statusNameVal = this.value
    console.log("Am I in change listner?");

    if (change_name_statusNameVal == "First") {
      id_value = 1000;
    } else if (change_name_statusNameVal == "Second") {
      id_value = 2000;
    } else if (change_name_statusNameVal == "Third") {
      alert("Are you sure you want to select third option?");
      id_value = 3000;
    } else if (change_name_statusNameVal == "Fourth") {
      id_value = 4000;
    }
  });

  $("#change_name_status").click(function() {
    $('#change_name_status').popModal({

      html: $('#name_status_popup_dialog').html(),

      onOkBut: function() {

        var change_name_statusNameVal = $("#change_name_statusName").val();

        if (change_name_statusNameVal == "First") {
          id_value_ = 1000;
        } else if (change_name_statusNameVal == "Second") {
          id_value_ = 2000;
        } else if (change_name_statusNameVal == "Third") {
          alert("Are you sure you want to select Third option?");

          id_value_ = 3000;
        } else if (change_name_statusNameVal == "Fourth") {
          id_value_ = 4000;
        }
      }

    });
  });
});
```

Also, notice that I attached the event listener on the `document` not the element itself since the element is dynamically generated.